# Panorama viewer is choppy for mobile phone (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, mobile-safari

I have a problem with "panorama viewer" that I have used for a website. If you open it through mobile phone and try to scroll the panorama, at the beginning it gets choppy. If you release your finger after the first scroll attempt and wait for a while, it gets smooth. I have experienced this problem using safari (Iphone XS)

Java script code:

```
    !function($){
  
  var defaults = {
    repeat: false,
    direction: "horizontal",
        animationTime: 700,
        easing: "ease-out",
        overlay: true
    };
  
    function touchHandler(event)
  {
      var touches = event.changedTouches,
          first = touches[0],
          type = "";

           switch(event.type)
      {
          case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
          case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
          case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
          default: return;
      }

      var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
      
      var mult = 2;
    
      simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                                first.screenX, first.screenY,
                                (first.clientX * mult), (first.clientY * mult), false,
                                false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);
      first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
  }
  $.fn.panorama_viewer = function(options){
    
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
    
    return this.each(function(){
      var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options),
      el = $(this);
      
      el.find("> img").ready(function () {
        el.find("> img").addClass("pv-pano");
        el.addClass("pv-container").wrapInner("<div class='pv-inner pv-animating'></div>");

        if (settings.direction == "vertical") {
           el.addClass("pv-vertical")
        }

        el.find(".pv-animating").css({
          "-webkit-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
          "-moz-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
          "-ms-transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing,
          "transition": "all " + settings.animationTime + "ms " + settings.easing
        })
        imgSrc = el.find(".pv-pano").attr("src")
        width = el.find(".pv-pano").width()
        height = el.find(".pv-pano").height()
        var repeat = "no-repeat";
        if (settings.repeat == true) {
          repeat = "repeat"
        }

        el.find(".pv-inner").css({
          height: height,
          width: width,
          background: "url(" + imgSrc + ") " + repeat,
          "background-size": "cover"
        })

        if (settings.overlay == true) {
          $("<div class='pv-overlay'><i class='pvicon-overlay'></i></div>").appendTo(el.find(".pv-inner"))

          el.find(".pv-inner").bind("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).find(".pv-overlay ").fadeOut("fast");
          }).bind("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).find(".pv-overlay ").fadeIn("fast");
          })
        }


        var $bg = el.find(".pv-inner"),
        elbounds = {
          w: parseInt($bg.parent().width()),
          h: parseInt($bg.parent().height())
        },
        bounds = {w: width - elbounds.w, h: height - elbounds.h},
        origin = {x: 0, y: 0},
        start = {x: 0, y: 0},
        movecontinue = false;

        function move (e){

          var inbounds = {x: false, y: false},
              offset = {
                  x: start.x - (origin.x - e.clientX),
                  y: start.y - (origin.y - e.clientY)
              };
          if (settings.direction == "horizontal") {
            if (settings.repeat == true) {
              inbounds.x = true;
            } else {
              inbounds.x = offset.x < 0 && (offset.x * -1) < bounds.w;
            }

            if (movecontinue && inbounds.x) {
                start.x = offset.x;
                start.y = 0;
            }
          } else {
            if (settings.repeat == true) {
              inbounds.y = true;
            } else {
              inbounds.y = offset.y < 0 && (offset.y * -1) < bounds.h;
            }

            if (movecontinue && inbounds.y) {
                start.y = offset.y;
                start.x = 0;
            }
          }

          $(this).css('background-position', start.x + 'px ' + start.y + 'px');


          origin.x = e.clientX;
          origin.y = e.clientY;

          e.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        }

        function handle (e){
            movecontinue = false;
            $bg.unbind('mousemove', move);

            if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
                origin.x = e.clientX;
                origin.y = e.clientY;
                movecontinue = true;
                $bg.bind('mousemove', move);
            } else {
              $(document.body).focus();
            }

            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }

        function reset (){
            start = {x: 0, y: 0};
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
        }


        $bg.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', handle);
        $bg.bind('dblclick', reset);

        el.find(".pv-pano").hide()
      })
      
      
    });
    
  }
  
}(window.jQuery);
```

I am attaching a link to a demonstration video: [Demo video](https://youtube.com/shorts/3Bgk9TjZqps)

The original code which I have used: https://github.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer

Also, you can check it yourself: https://www.gropenge.dk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you open the demo video you could see that when you start dragging the panoramic picture, it stutters at the beginning, and it should not. It should be smooth. It is only noticeable on the mobile phone. So I guess there is something to do with touch handler function.